# Hello everyone, I'm new at database. please help me to solve issues with mysql error logs

Tags: mysql

I get occasional error establishing database connection error on WP site. It happens regularly. To prevent it from happening again, I need to fix it, after the error I checked MySQL error logs and they are something like this

I AM READY TO PROVIDE MORE DETAILS IF NEEDED

```
[ERROR] mmap(137363456 bytes) failed; errno 12
[ERROR] Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
[ERROR] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
[ERROR] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
[ERROR] Data Dictionary initialization failed
[ERROR] Aborting
```

How do I know what causes it and how can I fix it?

This happens when I am not around. If 3-4 days go without signing in, it happens automatically. Then I have to restart the server to get back website working again. ↑ Those are errors I get in mysql error logs.

The website is live and database is working, but this error happens if I am not around and can't restart the server.

Information that should help you find out what is causing the crash:

```
usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 4892
Starting XA crash recovery...
XA crash recovery finished.
CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 5033
mmap(138353436 bytes) failed; errno 12
Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
Data Dictionary initialization failed
Aborting
```

Comment: How much RAM is available?  What is the setting of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  Let's see your entire `my.cnf` (or wherever the config file is).  What else is running in the same server (or VM)?  It sounds like a memory size problem.

Comment: Ram is 1GB. Standard wp installation.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions for your 1G server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan A:  Get more RAM.

Plan B:  Remove some other apps.

Plan C:  Decrease a setting:  `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 100M` and hope that it saves enough room without slowing down WP too much.